# Android app data storage keeps increasing

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, storage

I am developing an android app that basically loads up a list of news articles and opens them up in a webview upon user click.

What I'm wondering about is when I look at my app details in 'Settings->Applications->Manage Applications', the Total storage size keeps increasing. Particularly, the data storage size is increasing. The Application size of course, is fixed.

From what I know, the sharedpreferences take up data storage. I don't know what else. In my app, I just have 1 checkbox preference and a listpreference with 4 items.

I also implemented the `onSaveInstanceState()` method where I just save a single int value and read up again during `onCreate()`.

Is the increasing data storage size normal or am I missing something? Maybe there should be some memory use cleanup I should do in my code?

By the way, my app has quite a big cache size due to the webview caching some images maybe but I don't know what makes the data storage keeps increasing.

Comment: Does it increase at a linear rate? or does it increase sporadically? Ie if you go to a website and hit refresh does it increase? if you got to 100 websites does it go up by 100 or does it fluctuate. Try to figure out if your leaking something or if its chrome caching. Caching should be sporadic and can be tested for. leaks should be a little more constant.

Comment: I'm playing with it to see how the data size change base on what I do. As of now, what i'm seeing is that it increases when I load a page on the webview. But not all the time. I don't have a refresh option on my webview so I can't try it out. Isn't the cache supposed to go in the cache size (which is quite big right now) rather than data size?

Comment: Here's a sample how the size changes. I basically load up the same page (a small simple article site) for the first 5 data. The last one, I opened up a different article ( a much bigger/complicated site) and the change to the data is a lot bigger.  
  
Data Cache  
520KB 5.53MB;  536KB 5.58MB;  
540KB 5.60MB;  
548KB 5.62MB;  
552KB 5.64MB;  
568KB 6.16MB;

Comment: You can try [turning off the cache in the WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setCacheMode(int)) and see if that helps.

Comment: @dmon Is it really supposed to take up the data storage size and not just the cache size if the webview is caching websites? I kinda don't want to turn off caching cuz I want it to be able to load up websites fast. How do I know for sure that what's causing the data size to increase is the webview caching sites and not some leak like ntkachov mentioned above.

Comment: I didn't mean disable the caching forever, just turn it off and see if the data size stays the same.

Answer (score 4):

I know that is over 2 years, but it could be useful for someone else. I discovered that the problem resides in the `WebView` and not in the `SharedPreferences`
I had the same problem and solved by overriding the `onPause()` method in this way:

```
private WebView wv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    wv = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(wv);
    wv.loadUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    wv.clearCache(true);
}
```

The [clearCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#clearCache%28boolean%29) method takes a boolean argument that lets you specify whether you want to include disk files that the WebView stores. If you enable it your data usage will significantly decrease. Hope it helps!