# Android App's user data keeps increasing : room database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room

I recently learnt room database and made a note making application. The app follows MVVM design pattern and the user can insert/delete/update notes.


The problem is that for every insert/update/delete , the app's size is increasing.

I  checked the phone settings-> Applications-> SimpleNoteApp -> Storage and these are my observations.

1. The "App size" is fixed. - 15.16 mb
2. The "user data" keeps on increasing for every database operation.
3. "cache" doesn't increase no matter how many times I perform db operations
4. The total app's size is a sum of 1),2), 3)

So this means if I keep using the app for quite a while and even if I delete all the notes in the app, the "User data" will be a cumulative sum of every db operation performed. Correct me if I'm wrong.

There is a similar question on Stack OverFlow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146425/android-app-data-storage-keeps-increasing), but it doesn't solve the issue.

As for the coding part, there isn't much going around as these are basic examples of room database, I use " @Update @Insert @Delete " commands.

Comment: I think it's a normal behaviour for this case, try to make 100_000 inserts and check the final size, then clear all tables and check it again...

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much man. @MaximFirsoff

Answer (score 0):

> So this means if I keep using the app for quite a while and even if I delete all the notes in the app, the "User data" will be a cumulative sum of every db operation performed. Correct me if I'm wrong.

This is incorrect.  Deleting the rows should remove the data from storage...more or less.  There is a [write-ahead logging/rollback journal](https://sqlite.org/wal.html) that may mean it persists temporarily, so if it's important for security, you'll have to be more careful.  This may also result in temporary per-database-operation increases in the short-term.  However, in the long term, if your app's storage size is continuing to grow despite deleting all content from the database, something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since the developer is not responsible for collecting the garbage, this is actually normal as suggested by @MaximFirsoff in the comments

I ran a test which did 100_000 inserts, and deletions and observed the changes to the storage.

Observation
The garbage is collected after the "UserData" reaches a threshold limit and the data is cleared.

Comment: This is basically what [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63823433/208273) says.

Comment: @RyanM  I'm sorry Ryan. Since I just got started with this, I wasn't sure how to check if it would persist in my app in the long term, I had few questions after reading your answer. But Your answer makes sense now. Thank you too. Cheers